# Play framework + Selenium web driver + cucumber stucks on the first http request

Tags: selenium, playframework, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to set up a BDD environment with play 1.2.6 (java), cucumber-jvm (via https://github.com/jeromebenois/play-cucumber) and selenium web-driver.

If I use selenium in a simple junit test (non-cucumber) to test the login, selenium works fine... the first http request receive a 302 response, I'm redirected to localhost:9000/login and I can login. But if I use selenium in a cucumber scenario the driver (firefox-driver) stucks on the first http request to localhost:9000 waiting for the 302 response that never arrives until the timeout exception is fired.
While waiting for that response, if I try to access localhost:9000 from another browser, it will stuck as well.

I really don't know how to find the source of the problem, I'm crawling in the dark for 4 days now. Here the log: http://pastebin.com/FZXUBq6r

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a code snippet that reproduces this? Are you extending any classes in your test?

The @Before behaviour of JUnit and Cucumber is different; JUnit will execute the @Before of classes that it extends, whereas Cucumber will not.